# Controlador laravel moficar para hacer busqueda con mas de un producto

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente controlador:

```
public function show($id)
       {
         // Busco  el perfil
         $perfil = lista::where('di', $id)->first();

        //con el resultado de la busqueda muestro el perfil
        $mostrarperfil = Perfiles::where('id', $perfil['di'])->get();

           return view('products.show', compact('mostrarperfil'));
       }
```

Este controlador me funciona correctamente, pero lo que necesito es hacer esto pero con varios perfiles a la vez, a ver si me explico.
Quiero cambiar esto:

```
$perfil = lista::where('di', $id)->first();
```

Por esto:

```
$perfil = lista::where('di', $id)->get();
```

Así me daría varios resultados pero no se que cambios le tendria que hacer a este para poder mostrar todos los perfiles que me arroje $perfil:

```
$mostrarperfil = Perfiles::where('id', $perfil['di'])->get();
```

espero que se entienda intente hacer un foreach pero no lo consigo ademas no se si es la forma correcta..

Estoy intentando hacerlo de la siguiente forma pero me sigue mostrando un solo resultado..

```
public function show($id)
       {
         // Busco  el perfil
         $perfil = lista::where('di', $id)->get();


       foreach($perfil as $perfi){
        //con el resultado de la busqueda muestro el perfil
        $mostrarperfil = Perfiles::where('id', $perfi->di)->get();
           }
           return view('products.show', compact('mostrarperfil'));
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu modelo Lista debes agregar la relacion que tiene con el perfil, asumiendo que una lista pertenece a un perfil(one to one):

```
public function perfil()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Perfil');
}
```

luego en tu consulta debes usar with:

```
$perfil = lista::with('perfil')->where('di', $id)->get();
```

Te devolvera un objeto que en sus atributos tendra uno llamado perfil que sera un array de objetos de la tabla perfil.